# Transaction Manager don't assume the transaction

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-transactions, spring-orm

i'm facing a problem i really dunno how to catch the cat tail (if you hollow me the joke :o))

i have a webapp in war, deploy in tomcat. the war contains 4 Jars. 
4 jars have 4 applicationContext, with 4 entityManager, and 4 TransactionManager.

declare like this (change the number 1..):

```
      <bean id="entityManagerFactory1" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" 
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource1"
    p:persistence-unit-name="com.xxxxxx.domain"     >

    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" 
        p:databasePlatform="${ds1.dbdialect}" p:generate-ddl="false"
            p:showSql="${ds1.showsql}"  />
    </property>
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
    </property>
</bean>

  <bean id="transactionManager1" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory1">
    depends-on="entityManagerFactory1" name="transactionManager1"/>


   <tx:annotation-driven  transaction-manager="transactionManager1" />
```

the context is load like this :

my problem i discover that when i'm using a BO of 3, the transaction is open with the datasource of 2.

moreover, if i do a persist i have the message :

AbstractSaveEventListener - delaying identity-insert due to no transaction in progress

BUT if i launch the jar 1 alone (for example), everything is working perfectly.

thanks a lot for your enlightement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me guess:

in your servlet-context.xml, do you import the contexts? e.g.:

```
<import location="classpath:context1.xml" />
<import location="classpath:context2.xml" />
```

etc.

If you do, all bean definitions are copied from the imported context into the root context, which means that you have four different `<tx:annotation-driven />` declarations, with different transaction managers. Probably the last one wins.

Possible solutions: Either [use Qualifiers](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-multiple-tx-mgrs-with-attransactional) or [use the XML style of transaction declaration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-diff-tx).

What I'd do is probably to introduce a custom `@Transactional` annotation per context:

```
@Transactional("tx1")
@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE,ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface Transactional1 {}
```

Now annotate all methods in jar 1 with `@Transactional1`, in jar 2 with `@Transactional2` etc. This mechanism is documented in the Section [10.5.6.3 Custom shortcut annotations](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-custom-attributes)

Comment: Thanks a lot !  i use the XML style of transaction declaration, because my version of spring is a little bit old.